# Executing a Dataflow job with multiple inputs/outputs using gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, google-cloud-dataprep

I've designed a data transformation in Dataprep and am now attempting to run it by using the template in Dataflow. My flow has several inputs and outputs - the dataflow template provides them as a json object with key/value pairs for each input & location. They look like this (line breaks added for easy reading):

```
{
    "location1": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table1",
    #...
    "location10": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table10",
    "location17": "project:bq_dataset.bq_table17"
}
```

I have 17 inputs (mostly lookups) and 2 outputs (one csv, one bigquery). I'm passing these to the `gcloud` CLI like this:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run job-201807301630 /
    --gcs-location=gs://bucketname/dataprep/dataprep_template /
    --parameters inputLocations={"location1":"project..."},outputLocations={"location1":"gs://bucketname/output.csv"}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) unrecognized arguments:
inputLocations=location1:project:bq_dataset.bq_table1,outputLocations=location2:project:bq_dataset.bq_output1
inputLocations=location10:project:bq_dataset.bq_table10,outputLocations=location1:gs://bucketname/output.csv
```

From the error message, it looks to be merging the inputs and outputs so that as I have two outputs, each two inputs are paired with the two outputs:

```
input1:output1
input2:output2
input3:output1
input4:output2
input5:output1
input6:output2
...
```

I've tried quoting the input/output objects (single and double, plus removing the quotes in the object), wrapping them in `[]`, using tildes but no joy. Has anyone managed to execute a dataflow job with multiple inputs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this via a huge process of trial and error. There are several steps involved.

#### Format of `--parameters`

The `--parameters` argument is a dictionary-type argument. There are details on these in a document you can read by typing `gcloud topic escaping` in the CLI, but in short it means you'll need an `=` between `--parameters` and the arguments, and then the format is key=value pairs with the value enclosed in quote marks (`"`):

```
--parameters=inputLocations="object",outputLocations="object"
```

#### Escape the objects

Then, the objects need the quotes escaping to avoid ending the value prematurely, so

```
{"location1":"gcs://bucket/whatever"...
```

Becomes

```
{\"location1\":\"gcs://bucket/whatever\"...
```

#### Choose a different separator

Next, the CLI gets confused because while the key=value pairs are separated by a comma, the values also have commas in the objects. So you can define a different separator by putting it between carats (`^`) at the start of the argument and between the key=value pairs:

```
--parameters=^*^inputLocations="{"\location1\":\"...\"}"*outputLocations="{"\location1\":\"...\"}"
```

I used `*` because `;` didn't work - maybe because it marks the end of the CLI command? Who knows.

Note also that the `gcloud topic escaping` info says:

> In cmd.exe and PowerShell on Windows, ^ is a special character and
>       you must escape it by repeating it. In the following examples, every time
>       you see ^, replace it with ^^^^.

#### Don't forget `customGcsTempLocation`

After all that, I'd forgotten that `customGcsTempLocation` needs adding to the key=value pairs in the `--parameters` argument. Don't forget to separate it from the others with a `*` and enclose it in quote marks again:

```
...}*customGcsTempLocation="gs://bucket/whatever"
```

Pretty much none of this is explained in the online documentation, so that's several days of my life I won't get back - hopefully I've helped someone else with this.

Comment: hello Adam, thanks for this post. it helped me deploy my pipeline. On a different note,  are you doing all the ETL operations via java script. is there a reference article I can refer to , to help develop complex ETL operations on Dataflow. any pointers will help a lot.

Comment: @akashsharma no, we're using Cloud Dataprep, which generates a Dataflow template