# Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get value for location1"

Tags: templates, gcloud, dataflow

The following is the error message generated when I try to run a `dataflow` job. More specifically, I execute the dataflow job using a template that is created by executing a flow in `dataprep`.

The command I am running in the gcloud shell is:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run_template       
--gcs-location gs://[bucket]/templates/sample_template        
--parameters   
   inputLocations=gs://[bucket]/input/input_file.csv,   
   outputLocations=gs://[bucket]/output/my _output
```

- **Error message:**

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get value for location1"

- **Detailed description of the error:**

> "Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
>   Unrecognized token 'gs': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at
>   [Source: (String)"gs://[bucket]/input_file.csv"]

So, I'd like to know the correct command to run the job?

**Note**:
When I used `inputFile` and `outputFile` in `--parameters` as mentioned in the documentation below, it throwed me an error. So, I instead used `inputLocations` and `outputLocations` which solved the error.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates#example-1-custom-template-batch-job_1

Answer (score 0):

The `--parameters` flag is a dictionary-type, you should no allow spaces between the comma separated parameters. Also `inputLocations/outputLocations` parameters takes objects. You will have to enclose the objects in curly braces `{}`, enquote it's fileds with `""` and escape the commas. It's quite tricky to get this to work on the CLI. You can find references in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping), but a complete explanation on how to make it work was provided in this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51784105/8456296).