# How to set defaultWorkerLogLevel while invoking dataflow job from template?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I know we can configure worker log levels using --defaultWorkerLogLevel=level option through command line while running dataflow job directly from local or while creating template.

But I want to know how to use this option while invoking dataflow job from previously built templates where we didn't use this option while building it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply set that parameter when invoking the job from a previously built template (either with CLI or API) - you don't have to recompile and stage the template again.

Format of parameters when using `gcloud` CLI is described well here [Executing a Dataflow job with multiple inputs/outputs using gcloud cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751763/executing-a-dataflow-job-with-multiple-inputs-outputs-using-gcloud-cli/51784105#51784105)

If you're using the API it depends on the SDK you have chosen - for example, Terraform makes it easy https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dataflow_job#parameters

Comment: It will be helpful if you can be more specific on how to include that option either in CLI or API